# What's the correct meaning of the "Shadow DOM"?

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

I want to make a correct translation of the "Shadow DOM" term into Russian. But I'm not sure what the meaning is the most appropriate for the word "shadow". So I've composed a list of different meanings. Please help me to choose  the best one.

- shade, ghost, dark, reflection, loom
- ghost, specter, phantom, apparition, wraith
- darkness, gloom, obscurity, night, murk
- twilight, semidarkness, shade
- hint, allusion, reference, suggestion, inkling
- cover, covering, veil, coat, blanket
- secondary, supernumerary

Comment: Not sure that this question is a good fit for SO, but "cover" is probably the best in the list.  Think of Shadow DOM as being a glass box in that you can see what's inside, but you can't actually touch/manipulate the contents (similar to how you can't catch your shadow).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language.

Comment: It's about understanding of the specification.

Comment: The shadow is in the sense of what the sun projects from an object to the opposite surface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "shadow" in this context means "secondary" or "supernumerary". They're not in your list of synonyms because your thesaurus sucks.

Comment: Really good one meanings. I've added them to the list.

Comment: @Oleg I actually think that "shadow" is a very poor choice in English. It doesn't assist English speakers to understand what the technology is about, and it clearly doesn't assist you.

Answer (score 2):

From the [**Shadow DOM Working Draft**](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/):

> This specification describes a method of establishing and maintaining functional boundaries between DOM trees and how these trees interact with each other within a document, thus enabling better functional encapsulation within the DOM.
>
> ...
>
> Web application developers often encounter the need to provide encapsulation within a DOM tree. Despite being part of one document tree (a tree that has document as its root), there are typically many functional tree fragments, as well as assumptions about these fragments operating independently. This specification calls this type of encapsulation a functional encapsulation, as opposed to trust encapsulation, which deals with limiting information flow based on trust and ensuring security of data and state within an application.
>
> ...
>
> The shadow DOM allows multiple DOM trees (in addition to the document tree) to be composed into one larger tree when rendered. The existence of multiple DOM trees is enabled by letting any element in the document tree to host one or more additional DOM trees. These shadow trees are governed by a set of rules that establish encapsulation boundaries while retaining the standard DOM composability semantics.
>
> The encapsulation boundaries between the document tree and shadow trees are called shadow boundaries. The elements that host shadow trees are called shadow hosts, and the roots of the shadow trees are called shadow roots.

It's also worth noting that there's a [shadow-dom](/questions/tagged/shadow-dom) tag whose [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shadow-dom/info) states:

> The Shadow DOM allows you to include a subtree of DOM elements into the rendering of a document, but not into the main document DOM tree.

Its wiki also links off to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom which describes the purpose and usefulness of the Shadow DOM in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, but from your answer it isn't clear for me, what is your proposition.

Comment: @Oleg personally I'd say that it's been called the Shadow DOM because the majority of its content is essentially hidden from the outside world, *lurking in the shadows*. This, as mentioned throughout the Working Draft, is [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).